# Graphene Authentication or other check for all mutations

Tags: python, graphene-python, graphene-django

Is there any way to apply decorator/authentication or some kind of other check to ALL mutations?

For example:

```
class Mutations(graphene.ObjectType):
    some_mutation = SomeMutation.Field()
    some_mutation2 = SomeMutation2.Field()
    some_mutation3 = SomeMutation3.Field()

graphql_schema = graphene.Schema(query=Queries, mutation=Mutations)
```

I know that I can apply decorator for "mutate" or "mutate_and_get_payload" inside every mutation like this:

```
class SomeMutation(relay.ClientIDMutation):
    class Input:
        some_uuid = graphene.UUID()

    success = graphene.Boolean()

    @classmethod
    @login_required
    def mutate_and_get_payload(cls, root, info, *inputs):
        ...
```

Is it possible to somehow apply it to everything at once?
For example at class Mutations level.

Adding it to every mutation works fine, but applying it for 100 mutations is quite tiring.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a possible way to achieve this, that works with Graphene v2.1.9.

You can redefine the `Mutation.Field` classmethod, the resolver passing part specifically, like this:

```
from graphene import Mutation, Field


class MutationWithAuth(Mutation):
    class Meta:
        abstract = True

    # App-wide decorators for all mutations
    decorators = [login_required]  # <-- list your desired decorators here

    @classmethod
    def Field(cls, name=None, description=None, deprecation_reason=None, required=False):
        resolver = cls._meta.resolver
        for decorator in cls.decorators:
            resolver = decorator(cls._meta.resolver)  # <-- here we apply them

        return Field(
            cls._meta.output,
            args=cls._meta.arguments,
            resolver=resolver,
            name=name,
            description=description or cls._meta.description,
            deprecation_reason=deprecation_reason,
            required=required,
        )
```

And then you just write your mutations with this base class `MutationWithAuth` as usual:

```
class SomeMutation(MutationWithAuth):
    ...

    @extra_custom_decorator
    def mutate(self, info, input):
        ...
```

You can also override these "global" decorators in a particular mutation like:

```
class SomeOtherMutation(MutationWithAuth):
    decorators = []  # <-- like this
```

I am not sure if it's the most elegant one, but it is better than sticking a decorator on top of each `def mutate` line.

It works even if you still want an option to occasionally add some extra decorators to your mutation methods.